# integrating a cms wordpress with an existing website

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

We have this website getvital.in and as per the requirement of content team , we need to integrate wordpress cms in this website .We have our app written in reactjs and some pages in html and css which are basically landing pages for marketing .I don't understand as what this integration means and how we should go about this .
Any help will be highly appreciated .

Comment: How about just moving all the content (articles, images) manually to WordPress, then pick a theme that allows for heavy customization, as well as a page builder, such as Elementor, so you can redesign your website on WordPress. If you need any custom functionality, you can develop a WordPress plugin.

Comment: Hey we only want landing pages using wordpress and nothing more than that

Comment: Then install Wordpress on your website, install a page builder plugin such as Elementor to create your landing page. Easy as that.

Comment: any article to do all this . we have used create-react-app to build the app .what do you mean by install wordpress on your website

Comment: I don't really understand where you are stuck. You say you have a website getvital.in and it needs to be turned into a WordPress based website, right? So where is the issue? Check YouTube on how to install WordPress and how wordPress works. How is your app related to the website? Wouldn't that be a separate product?